# Unwanted space between img and figcaption inside figure

Tags: html, css

Why there's white space between an img and figcaption inside figure?
margin and padding of both img and figcaption are 0.

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}

figcaption {
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .5);
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/61af86922698a8cd422f77ae2343d2a5?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
  <figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
</figure>
```

(I'm not asking how to remove this space, I'm asking why it's there.)

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/ hope this link will provide some info

Answer (score 20):

As `image` is a `inline element` it gives extra space at the bottom you can fix it by giving `vertical-align`

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
figcaption {
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .5);
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/61af86922698a8cd422f77ae2343d2a5?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
  <figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: After this answer informed me that img is an inline element, I decided on img { display: block; }

Answer (score 6):

All you need is add a **display: block** in **img** tag.

```css
img {
   width: 200px;
   background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .5);
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
  <figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 4):

In HTML the images will effectively act like words.

You could use CSS. Setting display:block, or float:left on the images will let you have define your own spacing and format the HTML however you want but will affect the layout in ways that might or might not be appropriate.
Add this CSS:

```
img {
   width: 200px;
    display:block;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0fgxz28d/3/)

Answer (score 3):

The space is there due to Line-Height of the font present in figcaption element. Set the line-height of the figcaption the same as its font-size. Or lesser.

something like

```
figcaption {
    line-height:4px;
}
```

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/0fgxz28d/1/)

Link explaining how Line-Height works http://joshnh.com/2012/10/12/how-does-line-height-actually-work/

Hope this helps.