# space between an inline-block element and a block element

Tags: html, css

What is that space between these two divs? I even removed the white space in html.

```
<div id="asd"></div><div id="psd"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9thpuvwa/

Now, if the first div (asd) has some text in it, the space is gone; WHAT?

```
<div id="asd">a</div><div id="psd"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kadb1d3s/

(I'm trying to understand [my prev question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160231/unwanted-space-between-img-and-figcaption-inside-figure))

CSS

```
#asd {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#psd {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;   
  height: 200px;
}
```

The question: Where that space is coming from?

Comment: @MateiMihai this is actually a different issue. Setting `line-height` will not fix this problem.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly the second answer on that question is exactly the solution for this question.. He may try all those answers before asking again..

Comment: @MateiMihai, you're right. At the time of writing this question, I did not saw that answer. I've refreshed but! I have no idea why my browser didn't update the page.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be caused by the vertical alignment. Where it's set to `inline-block`, by default the vertical alignment is set to `baseline`, which is slightly higher raised (probably to account for characters like 'y' and 'g' which dip below the line).

`vertical-align` of `top` seems to fix it:

```css
#asd {
  ...
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9thpuvwa/1/).

Answer (score 1):

> Where that space is coming from?

From the `inline-block` element being aligned to the `baseline` of the “line” it is displayed on.

Add `vertical-align:bottom` (or `text-bottom`, or `middle`, or`top`, …) to it, and the space will be gone: http://jsfiddle.net/9thpuvwa/2/