# Header tags push parent element down

Tags: html, css

so, this turned out to be a duplicate question:
[space between an inline-block element and a block element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165162/space-between-an-inline-block-element-and-a-block-element). I just worded my question wrong when searching the site.

I have my site code that I put up in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mktd/Lxh7hsbu/)

Here is my html:

```
<div id="main">
    <section class="section-left">
        <header><h1>My Name</h1></header>
        <content>
            <p></p>
        </content>
    </section><section class="section-right">
        <header><h3>Hello World!</h3></header>
        <content>
            <p></p>
        </content>
    </section>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
#main {
    background-color:blue;
    height:92%;
}

#main section {
    display:inline-block;
}

.section-left{
    width:30%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
}

.section-right{
    width:70%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:orange;
}
```

When I take out the h* tags, the section elements go back to being displayed correctly with no space in them. But, as soon as I put a h tag in them, the section-left either moves nearly all the way to the bottom, or if I add a border to section-left (which i found on another forum) it pushes section-right down below it.

The only thing I can find that happens, is when viewing thru the chrome dev tools is a:

```
webkit-margin-before:.83em;
webkit-margin-after:.83em;
```

Can anyone see if I am doing something incorrect on this?

Also, if I were to just change it for the two sections (which I may put into article tags?) to
    float:left;

What type of code would I need to insert to make it appear like it does now?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: @j08691 invalid how?

Comment: The content element can't be a child of the section element.

Comment: i see. not sure where i got putting the content element into the section element, but it was probably in one of the several youtube tutorials i have watched. thanks for letting me know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

section defaults to `vertical-align: baseline;`

```
#main section {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;  /* Add this to overide */
}
```

Comment: even tho this is a duplicate, i'm marking your answer as correct, bc it is an answer to the question. i hope that is alright.